# Casting to subtype in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a map declared as follows:

```
private var iCacheMap: HashMap[Class[_ <: ICacheable], String] = ....
```

So the key for this iCacheMap is a class that implements the ICacheable interface

I am then looking to query this map, as follows:

```
private def queryICacheMap(message: AnyRef) {
    val iCacheable = message.asInstanceOf[ICacheable] 
    val myString = iCacheMap.get(classOf[iCacheable]).get
    // ...do something with myString
}
```

However, I get a type mismatch exception explaining that we are expecting a Class[_ <: ICacheable], but the actual is Class[Any]

What do I need to do to cast this correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can safely use pattern matching:

```
message match {
  case iCacheable: ICacheable => iCacheMap.get(iCacheable.getClass).getOrElse("Not Found in Map")
  case _ => //manage the "else" case
}
```

classOf[T] is useful when you have a static type that you want information about; if you need to retrieve the same information from an instance you can use getClass.

Comment: Not sure I follow, the compilation error in my above example was for the classOf[iCacheable]. Can you show how the above answer resolves this? Thanks

Comment: I immproved the example. You have to use getClass.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var iCacheMap: Map[Class[_ <: ICacheable], String] = Map()
//populate iCacheMap; message comes along
myString = message match {
  case iCacheable: ICacheable => iCacheMap.getOrElse(iCacheable.getClass, "Nothing")
  case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not good")
}
```